# how to get data groupBy email from database in Laravel 6

Tags: mysql, api, laravel-6.2

I have the same email ids in multiple times in database, I need to get and display all users excluding duplicates.

Please help me to solve this issue

**expected output:**

```
[
    {
        "donation_id": "DMS1900001",
        "donor_name": "Naveen",
        "phone": "9164020904",
        "email": "naveen@vibhaa.in"

    },
    {
        "donation_id": "DMS1900032",
        "donor_name": "Naveen",
        "phone": "9164020904",
        "email": "abhilash@vibhaa.in"
    }
]
```

**My Code:**

```
$donordata =  DB::table('donors')
                      ->groupBy('email')
                        ->get();
         return $donordata;
```

**And the Response**

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'minidms_db.donors.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL:
        select * from `donors` group by `email`)
```

**But the data is in Table:**

```
[
    {
        "donation_id": "DMS1900001",
        "donor_name": "Naveen",
        "phone": "9164020904",
        "email": "naveen@vibhaa.in",
    },
    {
        "donation_id": "DMS1900002",
        "donor_name": "Naveen",
        "phone": "9164020904",
        "email": "naveen@vibhaa.in",
    },
    {
        "donation_id": "DMS1900035",
        "donor_name": "Naveen",
        "phone": "9164020904",
        "email": "abhilash@vibhaa.in",
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you really want JSON ? Or is this format here to show us what you want?  See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also does Laraval not support PDO fetch modes to join a array to a [GROUP](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would just do a distinct select here:

```
$donordata = DB::table('donors')
                 ->distinct()
                 ->get();
```

The issue here, as mentioned by the error message, is that you are doing a `SELECT *` but you are only grouping by a single column:

```
select * from `donors` group by `email`
```

If you wanted to use a `GROUP BY` approach to remove duplicates, then you *could* have used:

```
SELECT donation_id, donor_name, phone, email
FROM donors
GROUP BY donation_id, donor_name, phone, email;
```

But, just calling Laravel's `distinct()` function is a bit easier in this case.

Comment: *"The issue here, as mentioned by the error message, is that you are doing a SELECT * but you are only grouping by a single column:"* When used with MySQL 5.7.5+ with enabled only_full_group_by sql_mode and a unique key on email then using `select * from donors group by email` is perfect valid ANSI SQL 1999+  functionally dependency wise .. Question is if `GROUP BY` indeed should be used to unduplicate..

Answer (score 0):

Edit your applications's database config file `config/database.php`

Update strict value on mysql to `false`

```
return [
   'connections' => [
      'mysql' => [
         'strict' => false
       ]
   ]
]
```

Comment: @NaveenNayak i am expecting you back very soon again when using this with questions like why data is corrupted/truncated/incomplete and or why queries with GROUP BY give invalid unmatching results..

Comment: @RaymondNijland oh ok thanks for the information.
I'm unable to resolve my issue using this solution
```$donordata = DB::table('donors')
                 ->distinct()
                 ->get();```